# How to create dashed bar graph in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have to create bar graphs as shown in the attached image using highcharts. The graph in the image has been created using Excel. But Highcharts doesn't seem to provide such feature. Though it allows to create graph using patterns but one doesn't have much control on those patterns. Can anyone please confirm if we can create similar kind of charts in highcharts or not? I have created a fiddle with highcharts for sample at http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepkparashar/6c48x39v/3/`Dashed Bar Chart`
[image: Dashed Bar Charts using Excel]

Comment: I would take a look at this plugin: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill

Comment: I have already looked at this plugin but they don't seem to fulfill my requirements in the sense that I need the patterns in dynamic colors.

Comment: Ok, client is ready to compromise with the idea that we can show "Not Mitigated" bars with dashed borders. Can someone please suggest how to do this (please refer to the JS fiddle link given in the question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comment, [pattern-fill plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill) can handle this.
You can create patterns and map the series, so every second column will have the corresponded pattern.

```
var colors = ["#FF0000", "#FF8C00", "#FFFF00", "#00FF00", "#3366FF"];

var series = [{
  "color": "#FF0000",
  "name": "High",
  "data": [298, 199, 448, 271, 772, 494, 935, 562]
}, {
  "color": "#FF8C00",
  "name": "Medium High",
  "data": [130, 32, 234, 172, 159, 134, 218, 160]
}, {
  "color": "#FFFF00",
  "name": "Medium",
  "data": [141, 163, 95, 63, 71, 22, 26, 13]
}, {
  "color": "#00FF00",
  "name": "Medium Low",
  "data": [42, 8, 34, 19, 16, 20, 21, 26]
}, {
  "color": "#3366FF",
  "name": "Low",
  "data": [4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}];

function getPatterns(colors) {
  return colors.map(function(color, i) {
    return {
      id: 'custom-pattern-' + i,
      path: {
        d: 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11',
        stroke: color
      }
   };
 });
}

function getMappedSeries(series) {
  return series.map(function(serie, i) {
    return {
      color: colors[i],
      name: serie.name,
      data: serie.data.map(function(value, j) {
        return j % 2 ? {
          y: value,
          color: 'url(#custom-pattern-' + i + ')'
        } : value;
     })
   };
 });
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/6c48x39v/8/

Natively, you can set border dash style for the series but you need to set dash style for the specific points, so you would have to split the series into dash/no border series or [extend Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts).

Comment: This is really awesome!! Can you please explain something about the pattern string 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11' ?